# How do i float two divs in a centered container with one of them bleed out to the edge of viewport

Tags: css, grid, css-float

Hi i'm sure this has been answered but i can't seem to find what i'm looking for.  I would like to have a container with a max-width and margin auto and then inside two divs floated next to each other (both taking 50% of the container) but the one on the right bleeds out the container right to the edge of the viewport?

As below with the dotted white line being the container and the black the browser.

[example here][1]

edit -  sorry i forgot to mention the divs need to both be the same height, so if the left has less content than the right it needs to still be the same height as the right, much like if i made them table-cell's.

```
.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 1260px;
}

.table{
    display:table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width:100%;

    .left, .right{
        display:table-cell;
        vertical-align: top;
        width:50%
    }
}
```

html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="table">
        <div class="left">
           content
        </div>
        <div class="right">
           content
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

I have tried adjusting it based on this answer but it stacks

http://jsfiddle.net/gxG4W/2/

Comment: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. I suggest you to read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please post what you have done so far using code snippet

Comment: I have edit the OP to what i have so far, i have tried using padding and negative margins but it stacks.  I'm not sure what to even try beyond that so i can't put any more in the example really

Comment: And i'm not asking anyone to code anything,  i have spent a lot of time trying to figure this out i would just like a little advice please in how to do this, not necessarily any code anything just in english what you would do.

Answer (score 0):

You should try bootstrap for this.
I hope this will help you.
Check out this by maximizing browser window.
[Bootstrap Column](http://jsfiddle.net/Asif92/Lph7gmv1/24/)

```css
.container {
  border: solid;
}

h4 { margin-bottom: 30px; }

.row {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.row .row {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.left-div
{
  border: solid red;
}
.right-div
{
  border: solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
        <h4>Two Columns</h4>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 left-div">
      <p>
        test div      
      </p>
      <p>
        test div      
      </p>
      <p>
        test div      
      </p>
      <p>
        test div      
      </p>
      <p>
        test div      
      </p>
      <p>
        test div      
      </p>
      <p>
        test div      
      </p>
      <p>
        test div      
      </p>
      <p>
        test div      
      </p>
      <p>
        test div      
      </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 right-div">
      <p>
        test div      
      </p>
      <p>
        test div      
      </p>
      <p>
        test div      
      </p>
      <p>
        test div      
      </p>
      <p>
        test div      
      </p>
        </div>
      </div>
         
    
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for taking the time to reply, i don't think that is working or what i want though thanks, and i can't use bootstrap.  This is sort of what i'm trying to do, i've almost got it working but i just don't think this is the best way to do it

https://jsfiddle.net/shbkxcgw/

Comment: Actually i can't really us that as the absolute won't adjust its parents height :(

Comment: Remove `position:absolute` and `right:0` properties from the `css` of right div.

Answer (score 0):

ok i've pretty much fixed this myself now, i'm not sure if its the best way to do it and it doesn't make the div's equal height as with the table trick, so i will need to us js to do that i guess.  But here is my solution.

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="left">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </div>
      <div class="right">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </div>
  </div>
```

css

```
.container{
  max-width:500px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:red;
  padding:10px 0;
}

.container::after{
  content:" ";
  clear:both;
  display:block;
  float:none;
}

.left{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  background:green;
}

.right{
  background:blue;
  width:50vw;
  margin-left:50%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/shbkxcgw/4/